# Contribution Completed but not received

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, authorize.net

My client's site recorded this item as complete with the recorded credit card. However, Authorize.net claims to have no record of this transaction and the event registree says that she has no record of the transaction from card provider. The site is  running Civi 5.13 on Wordpress 5.2. I'll take any suggestions on how to track this down and prevent if from happening again. For the record, this is not multisite. There are no other accounts or processors available for this site. [image]

Comment: only time i have seen this was when we had civirules involved and it resulted in payments being recorded as Completed when they were not. unlikely to be same, and CiviRules may have changed since then so the problem we had may not be replicable

Comment: I can confirm that CiviRules is not active on the site.

Comment: I don't use Authorize.net, but is there a transaction ID or anything like that on Civi's end?

Comment: That's at the heart of the matter. Authorize.net should have dropped the Transaction ID into the database, as it does on others. In this case, the transaction ID is blank, even though it says completed.